# How to load a launchDaemon.plist without rebooting ios device?

Tags: ios, daemon, jailbreak, launch

I wrote a launchDaemon.plist, and put it into `/System/Library/LaunchDaemon/`.

How can I load it without rebooting my iOS device?

Answer (score 1):

If you login to your iOS device via `ssh`, you can use this from the command line:

```sh
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/launchDaemon.plist
```

And of course, to stop the daemon

```sh
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/launchDaemon.plist
```

**Note:** if you are going to release this as a *product*, not just for your own use, I recommend following normal naming conventions, and name your plist file something like `com.mycompany.MyCrazyDaemon.plist`.

Reference: [Apple OS X docs on launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).